# Rpi to arduino via USB

Tags: usb, serial, uart

I am a little bit hazy about the serial ports on the RPI. I am using GPIO pins 14 and 15 to connect to my GPS. Can I at the same time use the USB port to connect serially to an Arduino? Or is there only one serial port that can be attached via the USB or the UART pins.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPIOs 14/15 are the TXD/RXD lines of the Pi's UART and can be used as a serial link.

In addition you can use as many USB serial dongles as you can plug in to the Pi or attached hubs to implement additional serial links.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose that as I have a wifi dongle and a memory stick  attached by USB I should have realized that! Old age strikes again. So now I suppose will have to workout how to read a particular com port in Python

Comment: @AlanJohnstone The Python serial module is the standard way (sudo apt-get install python-serial or python3-serial).  The USB serial device(s) will have names such as /dev/ttyUSB0.  An Arduino typically shows up at /dev/ttyAMC0.